# WSO2 EI 6.5.0 get specific string from json-eval expression value

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have below response from data service/wso2/

I wanna show only this string(<**SECURITYCODE  буруу байна!!!**>) in **errorMessage** **key**  from this :

```
{
        "Error": {
            "errorCode": 501,
            "errorMessage": "DS Code: VALIDATION_ERROR\nNested Exception:-\njavax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Code: VALIDATION_ERROR\nSource Data Service:-\nName: WSO2_COLLATERALINFO\nLocation: \\WSO2_COLLATERALINFO.dbs\nDescription: N/A\nDefault Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice\nCurrent Request Name: getCollateralInfo\nCurrent Params: {RegisterID=, Description=, AccountID=, Email=, RequestId=WSO2123456789, Telephone=, NationalID=, ProductID=, CustomerID=, CollateralType=, Source=WSO2, CollateralCode=COL0001843201, Function=CollateralInfo, LiabilityID=, UserId=egateway, CustomerName=, SecurityCode=B42B54464D1DF6000A3CA026BB2C6C0, RequestType=R}\nNested Exception:-\nSECURITYCODE  буруу байна!!! \nField Name: SecurityCode\nField Value: B42B54464D1DF6000A3CA026BB2C6C0\n\n"
        }
    }
```

How to to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a regex replace on the errorMessage and store the result in a property as follows.

```
<property name="securityCode" expression="replace(//errorMessage, '.*(SECURITYCODE.*?)\\.*', '$1')"/>
```

Keep in mind that you might have to enable xpath 2.0 on the EI to be able to use advanced xpath functions. You do this by setting the `synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled`  property to true in the synapse.properties file.

Another regular expression could be: `.*Nested Exception:-\\n(.*?)\\n.*`
Basicaly the regular expression matches the whole string as long as it contains the Nested Exception followed by a newline, followed by whatever you want to capture, followed by another newline. The capturing is done using the parenthesis, this creates a capture group which you reuse in the replace with $1 (which references to the first capture group, $2 to the second etc.)

You can adjust this to the requirements/errorMessage format.

To test your regular expressions you can always use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thank you for reply, What if SECURITYCODE has to be replaced with another string ?
i mean how to get string between according this two tags (Nested Exception and Field Name)
Nested Exception:- \nSECURITYCODE  буруу байна!!! \n Field Name:

Comment: You can just alter the regular expression to for example the following. This gets the part between NestedException and the next newline for example:
.*Nested Exception:-\\n(.*?)\\n.*